# mplayer (mplayerhq.hu) repeats ending audio frames

Tags: audio, codec, mplayer

mplayer (from mplayerhq.hu) on windows repeats the last few audio frames upon exit.
When the video ends, before you can see

> Exiting... (End of file)

in the command prompt, you will hear the last 1/2 second or so of the audio track again.
This behavior is the same for multiple containers/codecs/soundcards Vista or Windows 7.

Is there a workaround for this?

My playback specs:

```
MPlayer Sherpya-MT-SVN-r31027-4.2.5 (C) 2000-2010 MPlayer Team
150 audio & 343 video codecs

Playing splash_final.wmv.
ASF file format detected.
[asfheader] Audio stream found, -aid 1
[asfheader] Video stream found, -vid 2
VIDEO:  [WMV3]  1280x720  24bpp  1000.000 fps  6291.5 kbps (768.0 kbyte/s)
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [dmo] DMO video codecs
DMO dll supports VO Optimizations 0 1
DMO dll might use previous sample when requested
Decoder supports the following formats: YV12 YUY2 UYVY YVYU RGB8 [..]
Decoder is capable of YUV output (flags 0x1b)
Movie-Aspect is undefined - no prescaling applied.
VO: [directx] 1280x720 => 1280x720 Planar YV12
Selected video codec: [wmv9dmo] vfm: dmo (Windows Media Video 9 DMO)
==========================================================================
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
AUDIO: 44100 Hz, 2 ch, s16le, 329.8 kbit/23.37% (ratio: 41221->176400)
Selected audio codec: [ffwmav2] afm: ffmpeg (DivX audio v2 (FFmpeg))
==========================================================================
AO: [dsound] 44100Hz 2ch s16le (2 bytes per sample)
Starting playback...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"MPlayer Sherpya-MT-SVN-r31027-4.2.5" That is not the basic mplayer, sherpya build, MT. MT can cause problems sometimtes. I wrote an article about mplayer binaries under Windows.

Here it is: http://shiki.biomernok.hu/wp/?p=641
Basically just try a build without -mt and not by Sherpya.

---

Also, try to play around vo and ao. You can check your outputs with:
`mplayer -vo help` and `mplayer -ao help`
I use "gl" output because it renders a beautiful subtitle, better than any other player out there and I use `dsound` ao.

Comment: MPlayer SVN-r31139(20100507-gcc4.5.0) from sourceforge seems to be the only build that doesn't produce the audio glitch on my platforms. Thanks for the tip, i was beginning to think i hear voices.

Comment: The link in your post is dead; can you replace it or remove it? Thanks.